# Please help me formulate (and solve) a differential equation for a practical DIY problem concerning air sterilization (for covid)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, integration, differential-equations, intensity

[Here](https://old.reddit.com/r/COVIDProjects/comments/jtlfs6/diy_air_sterilizer_with_schematics_and_shopping/) I present the DIY air sterilisation project which this is about.

I want to calculate the overall sterilization rate of the device under some simplifying assumptions. (UVC is the hard ultra violet (UV) light killing the germs.)

[schema drawing](http://%20%20%3Cimg%20src=%22https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/e/2PACX-1vQXLE0yCNr574Sws-DpftJPp0AL7ocSwKTYFq6gubOucxGQFJLwNJsAw1x5-EvL9ZK37m2k3ypyxuCE/pub?w=960&h=720%22%3E)
[image]
I have

- the effective UVC power $E$ of my germicidal lamp. The lamp is a Hg-"neon" tube along the axis of the cylindrical device.
- the length $L$ of the lamp
- the radius $R_l$ of the lamp
- the inner radius $R_c$ of the cylinder
- a radius-invariant constant airflow through the cylinder (we are way into turbulent flow) with the speed $v$, so that I can calculate a mean residence time of the virus traveling through the killzone for
- a time $t =  L/v$
- the UVC irradiation intensity $I$ at a given radius $r$ in the cylinder $I(r) = \frac{E}{2\pi \, L \, r}$
- a irradiation dose $d(r) = I(r)*t$
- a virus-specific susceptibilty rate $k$ to calculate the specific killrate $P(r)=1-e^{-k \, d(r)}$
- a infinitisimal thin hollow cylinder (thickness $dr$) at radius $r$ around the axis of the cylinder with the volume $V(r) = 2  \pi  L \, r \, dr$ , which is proportional to the amount of germs exposed to the specific irradiation dose $d(r)$.

Now I look for the overall kill rate for the volume between $R_l$ and $R_c$.

Would it be correct to calculate  $\frac{1}{R_c - R_l}\cdot\int_{R_l}^{R_c} P(r) \cdot V(r)dr =  \frac{1}{R_c - R_l}\cdot\int_{R_l}^{R_c}2  \pi  L \, r \, (1-e^{-k   \frac{E}{2\pi\,v \, r}})   dr$ ?

Is that the differential equation I need?
What is a solution for that?

Comment: Your equation for killrate will indicate a rate of 1 for zero susceptibility.  So a virus immune to UV will be completely killed? Or I misunderstand something?

Comment: @nasu hu? $1-e^0 = 1-1 = 0$, right? zero susceptibility means zero kill means all viruses live. or do i misunderstand you?